# Time travel movie: guy wants to live in the past, travels there and meets another girl who wants to live even further in the past

Tags: identify-this-movie, time-travel

I'm searching a time travel movie about a guy who wants to live in the past. Somehow he was brought there and meets another girl. That other girl ironically wants to live even further in the past. 
I remember a scene of them both standing on a bridge when it begins to rain. They didn't bother and liked the romantic walk in the rain.

I think I saw the movie about at least 5 years ago and really don't remember the details well. The description could even be wrong.
Would appreciate if anybody knows the movie!

Further information requested (Although not sure):

Audio: German (dubbed though)

Country: Could be France

Tone: Romance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The movie is "Midnight in Paris (2011)", American-French romantic comedy film written and directed by Woody Allen.

> Set in Paris, the film follows Gil Pender, a screenwriter, who is forced to confront the shortcomings of his relationship with his materialistic fiancée and their divergent goals, which become increasingly exaggerated as he travels back in time each night at midnight.

The scene you described on the bridge, you can see [here.](https://youtu.be/FTseyjEt4Ho?t=109)

Comment: Wow! Yes that's it! As said, messed that description a little bit up :)